# Padding of array-like structs

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, padding

Given a struct that contains a sequence of the same fundamental types, like this:

```
struct Vector
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

Can it have padding **between** the members? I was given the link to [[class.mem]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-24) that says that padding may be added to achieve alignment but is it applicable in this case?

Comment: If the introduction of padding would be problematic for you, you can try to use `static_assert` to check at compile time. For example, `static_assert(sizeof(Vector) == sizeof(float) * 3, "");`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you cannot assume anything except that there is no padding before the first member, and that each individual type is correctly aligned. AFAIK padding between or after the members is conforming (though seemingly pointless).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not sure if it actually answer if there is a padding **between** the `Vector` members

Comment: @W.F. *where* would that padding go, if the size is just enough to fit the 3 floats?

Comment: @Quentin can't it be after the last one?

Comment: @W.F. no it can't. If `sizeof(Vector)` is three floats, and we know that a `Vector` contains at least 3 floats, then that doesn't leave a single byte anywhere for padding.

Comment: Anything may have padding if padding is required.  You can assert it at compile time, but all that does is stop your app from compiling.

Comment: @Donnie which is not that bad, given that users can fall down to compiler extensions to manipulate it.

Comment: @Quentin But if the `sizeof(Vector)` is more than three floats is this necessarily means that the padding is between the floats? In other words can't it give you false-negative assertion failure?

Comment: It is not ruled out by the standard. If you want an array, you might just as well use one...

Comment: @W.F. oh, *that* way around... My bad. yes, it could indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are no technical reasons for floats in a struct be aligned differently than in an array. But still there is *lack of standardization of C++ at the binary level*.

If you want to be safe, then you can add a `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(offsetof(Vector, y) - offsetof(Vector, x) == sizeof(float));
static_assert(offsetof(Vector, z) - offsetof(Vector, y) == sizeof(float));
```

Moreover you are also able to disable padding with a not cross-platform way. For Visual Studio, you need `#pragma pack` and for gcc, you need to use an attribute `packed`.

Comment: Can you provide a quote from the Standard? This is a language lawyer question.

Comment: @Lyberta There tend not to be quotes about lack-of-requirements

Comment: Is there certainly no way to make sure no padding occurs? This feels important enough to warrant a definitive answer.

Comment: @PasserBy And there **is** a definitive answer. Padding is implementation-defined. That's the end of it. And, while I'm not sure the second sentence in this answer would agree with me, _that's a good thing_. You want some way to control whether or not padding occurs? Read the documentation for your implementation.